# Doctrine modify query before execution

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm having a website that uses `pdo_mysql` as Doctrine driver to communicate with the database, everything is fine.

Now I'm attempting to write functional unit tests for my repositories and classes using `sqlite` as the database driver. However one query of mine is using `USE INDEX(index)`, and it looks like `sqlite` doesn't like that syntax.

Is there a way to modify all queries to remove the `USE INDEX(...)` string from the query before it goes to `sqlite` for execution?

Comment: found this https://gist.github.com/arnaud-lb/2704404  ( you have to alter it though )

Comment: yours is for adding index walker into the query, I wanted to remove it universally for `sqlite` on existing queries that are already using index walker

Comment: yeah, but the link was just for the approach you can take, viz. Creating a Custom Walker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think I can answer my own question.

I create a custom Connection class, extends from the default Connection, and override the `executeQuery()` function

```
class TestConnection extends Connection {

    public function executeQuery($query, array $params = array(), $types = array(), QueryCacheProfile $qcp = null)
    {

        $query1 = preg_replace('/USE INDEX\(\S+\)/', '', $query);
        return parent::executeQuery($query1, $params, $types, $qcp);
    }
}
```

Then define the parameters to create sqlite connection like this

```
    private $dbParams = [
    'driver' => 'pdo_sqlite',
    'memory' => true,
    'wrapperClass' => 'Sg\Test\Database\TestConnection'
];
```

and all queries are changed before execution